# Form with textarea and multiple files input option repeats the entry while uploading to database

Tags: php, database, forms, file-upload

I've form with two Text areas and a multiple file input field and I need to upload them to database ....
here is my HTML code

```
<form method="post" action="../php/new-upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div id="tabs-1">
            <textarea placeholder="Hi" name="n_head" class="n_head"></textarea>
            <textarea placeholder="Story..." name="n_st" class="n_st"></textarea>
            <div class="tg-it">
                <div class="tg-it-hd">Add Tag:</div>
                <input name="tags" id="singleFieldTags2" value="Election, Namo">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2" class="new-post-det">
            <div id="upload">
                <div id="drop">
                Drop Images Here
                or
                <a>Browse</a>
                    <input type="file" name="upl[]" multiple />
                </div>
                <ul>
                <!-- The file uploads will be shown here -->
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="new-ps-bt">
            <input type="submit" class="new-ps-bt" value="Post" />
            <a id="bk-bt"  class="bk-mn" href="../">Back &lt;</a>
        </div>
    </form>
```

and here is my new-upload.php file

```
<?php 
include("../config.php");
session_start();


    $n_head=$_POST['n_head'];
    $n_story=$_POST['n_story'];
    $n_up=$_SESSION["user_id"];
    $query = "INSERT INTO news(N_headline,N_story,N_U_id)VALUES('$n_head','$n_story','$n_up')";
    $data = mysql_query ($query)or die(mysql_error());
    $last_id = mysql_insert_id();

    foreach ($_FILES['upl']['name'] as $filename) {
    $n_img = $_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'];
    $query_1 = "INSERT INTO news_img(N_id,ng_img)VALUES('$last_id','$n_img')";
    $data_2 = mysql_query ($query_1)or die(mysql_error());
    }       

if($data)
{
header("Location:../");
}


mysql_close($con);
?>
```

so the problem is when this form is submitted, the database entry gets repeated the number of times same as the number of photos selected ....
help me out with this problem...

Comment: this `$_POST['n_story'];` to `$_POST['n_st'];`

Comment: as you have multiple images uploaded and your code is in loop then obviously the insert query will be executed as number of images

Comment: how should i solve the looping problem ??

Answer (score 0):

Please change these code in respective place

```
 $n_story = $_POST['n_story'];

    foreach ($_FILES['upl']['name'] as $filename) {
    $n_img = $filename;
    $query_1 = "INSERT INTO news_img(N_id,ng_img)VALUES('$last_id','$n_img')";
    $data_2 = mysql_query ($query_1)or die(mysql_error());
    }
```

Hope that fix your problem.

Comment: anyway you do not write multiple image upload code here. That's why i ignored the uploading process.

Comment: error comes... in the line of foreach and error says Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in \php\temp.php on line 12

Comment: if you don't select any files this error show you. better you encapsulate the foreach block into if condition like this if (isset($_FILES['upl']['name']) && !empty($_FILES['upl']['name'][0])) { foreach block here }. Now fix your problem.